# Installed Windows7, DVD Drives No Longer Recognized

Tags: windows-7, optical-media, hard-drive

I just wiped XP and installed Windows 7 on my PC.  The install went great, no errors reported.  However as I popped in some CDs to install some of my software, I notice that neither of my DVD drives are reading any cd/dvds.

When I open Windows Explorer the tree on the left does not show either device, but on the right screen it shows:  **DVD Drive (D:)**  and **DVD RW Drive (E:)**.  No matter what disc I put in there, *the computer does not read it*.  Clicking on the drive simply ejects it.

---

Steps I've taken so far:

1)  Checked Device Manager > DVD/CD-ROM drives:

> `SAMSUNG DVD-ROM SD-616E ATA
>   Device`
>   `SONY DVD RW DRU-700A ATA
>   Device`

Both show up as being fine, no yellow exclamation marks.  Device status is listed as "working properly".  Clicking on "Update Driver" results in "Your drivers are up to date".

2)  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`

In the right pane, right-click UpperFilters, and then click Delete.
In the right pane, right-click LowerFilters, and then click Delete.
Reboot.

Any other ideas on how I can get my DVD drives to get recognized?

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm "that guy".  I apologize and am ready to give up all of my "server fault points".  I don't know if I am more embarrassed, relieved, or angry.

The **THREE** software CDs that I tried to install were the problem and not my DVD drives.  All three have somehow gotten erased, i didn't even know this was possible.  I tried these disks on my laptop, and they were not recognized on there either.  So, I popped in a driver disk into my Win7 machine and voila, it worked.

Like I said, I'm sorry.  I thought one failure is normal, two failures is usually a sign of something wrong and three failures is doing due diligence.  Apparently not in this case.

Now, I am left scrounging around to see if I made any other backups of PhotoShop and Roxio Media Creator.  Thanks.

Comment: dont worry, happens to the best of us! You should be able to download previous versions that match your serial numbers.

Comment: You should either answer the question with this answer (I think you can do that after 48hrs), or get rid of the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other devices connected to the cable with the DVD-ROM drive?

How was the drive configured? Master or slave? Maybe you changed something on your computer and forgot to insert the master jumper?